# How to make a cover for a molten cake?

Tags: cake, dessert, fondant

I recently visited a restaurant called Zuma, and they had this unbelievable chocolate molten cake. [image]

As you can see they have a cover on top, like a sheet of chocolate. How would one make this? I am not particularly interested on they write the name(however that would be a bonus) but just the sheet to cover the top.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you taste it? It's probably just a thin sheet of chocolate that softened when put on the warm cake. You can buy thin sheets of chocolate with patterns printed on them in gold. (example: http://www.dr.ca/chocolate-transfer-sheets-wheat.html ) no affiliation I just did a search

Comment: @KateGregory That looks exactly right.

Comment: @KateGregory Great, thank you. Yes I did taste, and it taste just like melted chocolate. Time to try and make one of those myself!

Comment: I would suggest placing on the cake, THEN softening it with a distant torch :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that's a chocolate transfer sheet, which is just a very thin layer of chocolate with patterns printed onto it and then baked

Here's a link I found of someone doing this at home:

http://forums.egullet.org/topic/105238-demo-making-chocolate-transfer-sheets/

Comment: I don't think I'd call that the same ... they're printing onto plastic as a transfer medium, then applying the printed image onto the chocolate.  This might explain how they get the name onto the chocolate, but not how to make the thin chocolate sheet.  (the site linked to mentions the problem of the middle being thinner than the sides -- it's because the screen flexes as you print; you typically press the screen down to the printed surface before squeegeeing it ... the screen thickness is what affects the printed image's thickness.  (I worked for 2 years in our high school's print shop)